# Chinese characters can't correctly displayed after adding theme_void() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

For a test data set as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(c(1, 2), 3),
                 type = rep(c("甲级", "乙级"), 3),
                 country = rep(c("日本", "德国", "韩国"), each = 2),
                 count = c(19419, 1132, 8138, 947, 8349, 436))
```

I have drawn half-circles plot with the code below under **Mac OS** system:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=sqrt(count), fill=type)) + geom_col(width =1) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0.5, 2.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  coord_polar(theta = "x", direction = -1) +
  facet_wrap(~country) +
  theme_grey(base_family = "STKaiti" )
```

Out:

[image]

But after I add `theme_void()` to make the plot cleaner, then chinese character didn't display correctly.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=sqrt(count), fill=type)) + geom_col(width =1) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0.5, 2.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  coord_polar(theta = "x", direction = -1) +
  facet_wrap(~country) +
  theme_grey(base_family = "STKaiti" )+
  theme_void()
```

Out:

[image]

Does someone know why this happens and how to solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding the font line to theme_void?

Comment: Great, this solved the problem. You may answer the question and i'll accept it if you'd like to.

Comment: ggplot2 can only use one theme. It always uses the one last in the pipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the font to the `theme_void` line:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=sqrt(count), fill=type)) + geom_col(width =1) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0.5, 2.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  coord_polar(theta = "x", direction = -1) +
  facet_wrap(~country) +
  # theme_grey(base_family = "STKaiti" )+
  theme_void(base_family = "STKaiti")
```